# No puedo poner el focus(), jquery, el boton me roba el foco

Tags: jquery, focus

trabajando con PHP y jquery.

resulta que estoy validando la información enviada de un formulario. el la validación que me hace *mi modelo retorna 3 resultados: ok o campo duplicado o no null.*
recibo el resultado:

1. a) si es ok (muestro mi mensaje todo ok).
2. b) si es duplicado (muestro mi mensaje ) y pongo el foco en mi campo
   que tiene el campo duplicado(que es uno solo) .(aquí el problema, el
   foco se pone en el input pero inmediatamente el botón enviar me roba
   el foco).(sucede tan pronto se cierra el sweet alert)
3. c) los mismo para el resultado null.

```
<form method="POST" id="FormingreasarStand" enctype="text/plain">

  <input id="iptnroStand" name="nroStand" placeholder="ejem: 56" type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="10000" required autofocus>

  <input id="iptNPAsociado" name="NPAsociado" placeholder="ejem: 48" type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="10000" required>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnguardarstand">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // o return false;
  });
});

$("#btnguardarastand").on("click", function() {
  //alert("entro");


  var formulario = document.getElementById('FormingreasarStand');


  if (formulario.checkValidity()) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'esta seguro de registrar el Stand',
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Si, deseo registrarlo',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    }).then((result) => {

      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        var datos = new FormData();

        datos.append("accion", 'AddNewStand');
        datos.append("nroStand", $("#iptnroStand").val());
        datos.append("NPAsociado", $("#iptNPAsociado").val());
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax/stands.ajax.php",
          type: "POST", // error aqui puse method
          data: datos,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          dataType: 'json',

          success: function(respuesta) {
            if (respuesta == "ok") {
              Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'registro ok',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 3000,
              })
              table.ajax.reload();
              $("#iptnroStand").val("");
              $("#iptNPAsociado").val("");

            } else if (respuesta[2].indexOf("Duplicate") != -1) {
              swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'El stand ' + $("#iptnroStand").val() +
                  ' Ya esta registrado',
                text: 'No puedes registrar un stand que ya esta regitrado en la base de datos!',
                footer: respuesta,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 5000,
              })
              // aqui pongo el foco en el input dato incorrecto
              $("#iptnroStand").focus();
            } else if (respuesta[2].indexOf("null") != -1) {
              swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'El Número de padron: ' + $("#iptNPAsociado")
                  .val() +
                  ' no existe',
                text: 'El Número de padron que ingresaste no esta registrado en la base de datos!',
                footer: respuesta,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 3000,
              })
              // aqui pongo el foco en el input con dato incorrecto
              $("#iptNPAsociado").focus();
           
            } else {
              swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Erro al Registrar',
                footer: respuesta,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 5000,
              })
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedro, prueba a hacer el `focus` cuando se cierre la alerta. Por ejemplo...

```
swal.fire({
    icon: 'error',
    title: 'El stand ' + $("#iptnroStand").val() +
      ' Ya esta registrado',
    text: 'No puedes registrar un stand que ya esta regitrado en la base de datos!',
    footer: respuesta,
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 5000,
    didClose: () => {
        $("#iptnroStand").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: ¡Funciono! gracias perdí mas de 3 horas tratándolo de solucionar.